# Read line where is specific word in txt file

Tags: vb.net

I need to read the Config file for load settings.

My code:

```
        Dim preferences As FileInfo
        preferences = New FileInfo(".\settings.conf")

        If preferences.Exists Then
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(".\settings.conf")
            Dim tmpLine_theme As String

            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                tmpLine_theme = objReader.ReadLine()
                If tmpLine_theme.StartsWith("theme_selected: ") Then
                    tmpLine_theme = tmpLine_theme.Replace("theme_selected: ", "")
                    theme_box.Text = tmpLine_theme
                    MsgBox("Theme:" + tmpLine_theme)
                    theme_selected_var = tmpLine_theme
                Else
                    MsgBox("Not working")
                End If
            Loop
```

This code causes a loop, through which can't go on. 
I need to get the specific word, which then removes and retrieves the required data.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I need to search text in the file and pulled out the entire text of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you correctly,you are trying to get the line which contains specific word ? It isn't that hard , just a few lines of code :)

```
 Dim readFile as New List(of String)(File.ReadAllLine("path of file"))
 For each line in readFile
   If line.Contains("theme_selected: ") Then
    line.Replace("theme_selected: ","")
    MsgBox(line)
   End if
 Next
```

Comment: Simple and Works. :) 
Thank you very much zack. <3